# How to read files from the classpath in aws lambda java

Tags: java, classpath, aws-lambda

I'm seeing this error when I try to execute my `aws lambda function`

```
1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NullPointerException
at in.nikhilbhardwaj.path.route.resources.ServicesResource.<init>(ServicesResource.java:66)
at in.nikhilbhardwaj.path.route.resources.ServicesResource.class(ServicesResource.java:56)
while locating in.nikhilbhardwaj.path.route.resources.ServicesResource
for parameter 0 at in.nikhilbhardwaj.path.alexa.intent.HelloWorldIntentAction.<init>(HelloWorldIntentAction.java:44)
while locating in.nikhilbhardwaj.path.alexa.intent.HelloWorldIntentAction
while locating in.nikhilbhardwaj.path.alexa.intent.IntentAction annotated with @com.google.inject.multibindings.Element(setName=,uniqueId=10, type=MAPBINDER, keyType=java.lang.String)
at in.nikhilbhardwaj.path.alexa.intent.IntentModule.configure(IntentModule.java:17) (via modules: in.nikhilbhardwaj.path.alexa.AlexaStarterApplicationModule -> in.nikhilbhardwaj.path.alexa.intent.IntentModule -> com.google.inject.multibindings.MapBinder$RealMapBinder)
while locating java.util.Map<java.lang.String, in.nikhilbhardwaj.path.alexa.intent.IntentAction>
for parameter 0 at in.nikhilbhardwaj.path.alexa.intent.IntentHandlerServiceImpl.<init>(IntentHandlerServiceImpl.java:16)
while locating in.nikhilbhardwaj.path.alexa.intent.IntentHandlerServiceImpl
while locating in.nikhilbhardwaj.path.alexa.intent.IntentHandlerService
for parameter 0 at in.nikhilbhardwaj.path.alexa.AlexaStarterSpeechlet.<init>(AlexaStarterSpeechlet.java:26)
while locating in.nikhilbhardwaj.path.alexa.AlexaStarterSpeechlet
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:113)
at in.nikhilbhardwaj.path.route.resources.ServicesResource.initializeServiceIds(ServicesResource.java:88)
at in.nikhilbhardwaj.path.route.resources.ServicesResource.<init>(ServicesResource.java:68)
at in.nikhilbhardwaj.path.route.resources.ServicesResource$$FastClassByGuice$$3d6e91ec.newInstance(<generated>)
```

I've modified my code to read from the `classpath` and not the file system by following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java)

This is the line (Line 88 in ServicesResource.java) from where the exception is thrown -

```
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader()
    .parse(new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(RESOURCES_ROOT + RESOURCE_CALENDAR), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

and these are the constants that I'm using -

```
public static final String RESOURCE_CALENDAR = "calendar.txt";
public static final String RESOURCES_ROOT = "/path-nj-us/";
```

I think that I've packaged the code that I upload to `aws lambda` correctly, it works when I remove these references. Here's is what the `zip` contains (I've omitted unrelated files) -

```
➜  distributions git:(master) ✗ jar tf path-alexa-skills-kit.zip
in/
in/nikhilbhardwaj/
in/nikhilbhardwaj/path/
in/nikhilbhardwaj/path/route/
in/nikhilbhardwaj/path/alexa/
in/nikhilbhardwaj/path/alexa/AlexaStarterApplicationModule.class
in/nikhilbhardwaj/path/alexa/AlexaStarterSpeechlet.class
in/nikhilbhardwaj/path/alexa/AlexaStarterSpeechletRequestStreamHandler.class
in/nikhilbhardwaj/path/route/model/Constants.class
in/nikhilbhardwaj/path/route/resources/
in/nikhilbhardwaj/path/route/resources/ServicesResource.class
in/nikhilbhardwaj/path/route/resources/StopsResource.class
in/nikhilbhardwaj/path/route/resources/StopTimesResource.class
in/nikhilbhardwaj/path/route/resources/TripsResource.class
log4j.properties
path-nj-us/
path-nj-us/agency.txt
path-nj-us/calendar.txt
path-nj-us/calendar_dates.txt
path-nj-us/fare_attributes.txt
path-nj-us/fare_rules.txt
path-nj-us/feed_info.txt
path-nj-us/frequencies.txt
path-nj-us/route_directions.txt
path-nj-us/routes.txt
path-nj-us/shapes.txt
path-nj-us/stop_times.txt
path-nj-us/stops.txt
path-nj-us/timetable_stop_order-new.txt
path-nj-us/timetables-new.txt
path-nj-us/transfers.txt
path-nj-us/trips.txt
```

I would really appreciate any pointers to figure out what's missing here or general tips to debug this further. This is the first `aws lambda` function that I'm writing, so it's entirely possible that I glossed over something important in the documentation or don't know what to look for.

I've added some more debugging code and run it, it appears that the resources aren't available -

```
URL r = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("path-nj-us/calendar.txt");
if (r != null && r.getFile() != null) {
  System.out.println("Resource file name" + r.getFile());
} else {
  System.out.println("Resource not found in classpath");
}
```

This prints `Resource not found in classpath`. I've also tried the `this.getClass().getResource()` invariant with the same results.

I'll try posting to the `aws forums` to see if there is a known reason for this behavior or if reading files from the classpath is disallowed.

Answer (score 4):

Only two directories are accessed by awsLambda user code.

1. /var/task
2. /tmp

> all lambda functions keep the source code on /var/task

in your code, use anyone of this path instead of current directory path ***"path-nj-us"***. like this

```
URL r = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/tmp/calendar.txt");
if (r != null && r.getFile() != null) {
  System.out.println("Resource file name" + r.getFile());
} else {
  System.out.println("Resource not found in classpath");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Abdul, but path-nj-us isn't the current working directory. It is a directory inside my jar which contains the resources.

Comment: I did try this as well but I get not found for all these paths - /var/task/path-nj-us/calendar.txt /var/task/path-nj-us/calendar.txt  /tmp/calendar.txt and /tmp/path-nj-us/calendar.txt

Comment: This is helfu. I was able to read file and print its path which turned out to be /var/task/file-name.txt 
Here is how I read the file: 
`URL r = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("file-name.txt");
 System.out.println(r.getPath().toString());`

Comment: Yeah you can read and print from either /var/task or /tmp. But you can only write to /tmp which is allocated as part of lambda provisioning. /var/task is a read only path.